# How to extract specific column?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am dealing with mpg data in R. I want to learn which type of manufacturer that did not produce any manual cars? I need to draw a bar plot by using `str_remove()` function to edit the trans column so I can have clearer plot.

Can you help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `trans` column, every entry contains either the word "auto" or "manual", followed by some parentheses containing the transmission's sub-type. We can simplify this column into either just "manual" or "auto" by removing the parentheses using `str_remove`. Then we can remove the "auto" models, and count the number of models of manual transmissions per manufacturer. We can then plot the number of manual models per manufacturer.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>%
  mutate(trans = str_remove(trans, "\\(.*\\)")) %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(trans == "manual")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(manufacturer, count)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Number of manual transmission models produced per manufacturer")
```

[image]

We can see that Jeep, Landrover, Lincoln, Mercury and Pontiac have no manual transmission models in this data set.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question how to select certain columns or filter?

If it is how to select, then simply using the tidyverse package and you use the `select()` argument like below

```
df<- mpg %>% select(column_name)
```

if you want to filter a column then use `filter()` to pass an argument

```
df<- mpg %>% filter(column_name==argument_1)
```

Comment: I want to make barplot to see which manufacturers do not produce manual cars, but I could not overcome.

Comment: do you know which column indicates if the vehicle is manual or automatic?

Comment: "trans" column indicates it